# What does "Available in iOS x.x and later" mean?

Tags: ios

What exactly does this mean? I've seen Availability: iOS (6.0 and later) and other version numbers, but I don't think thats exactly what it means. Does it truly mean that its only available with iOS 6 and up? If thats the case, then why is the comparable method for iOS 2.0f and later depreciated? Shouldn't I still be using it when the iOS version is less that 6.0 or the specified availability?

An example is NSTextAlignmentCenter. It specifies that it is Availability: iOS (6.0 and later), but I'm building an app for iOS 4.3 and up. I'm currently performing a check on the iOS version of the device and choosing the text alignment between NSTextAlignmentCenter and UITextAlignmentCenter. To me, this seems odd. Shouldn't it be for iOS SDK 6.0 and later, rather than iOS 6.0 and later?

I know this seems like nitpicking, but it makes a pretty big difference.

Comment: Have you tried using a method marked "iOS 6 and later" in an app that targets iOS version earlier than 6? A quick test would probably answer your question.

Comment: @Caleb Well, I haven't tried that, but I'm still confused why it says depreciated. Thats what really threw me off.

Comment: Note that the term Apple uses is *deprecated*, not *depreciated.* Seems like nitpicking, but people will understand that you're talking about Apple's stance on a given method if you use the term that Apple uses. Methods marked 'deprecated in iOS 5' (for example) still exist in iOS 5 for compatibility with older apps, but you're on notice that they may go away in some future version. You should a) avoid using them in new apps, and b) update your existing apps to avoid using them. You may still need them if you're targeting an older iOS version, but you should understand the risk they present.

Comment: @Caleb Thats great! Thank you. So, essentially, applications that aren't updated all run the risk of incompatibility on future iOS versions, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've seen Availability: iOS (6.0 and later) and other version numbers,
>   but I don't think thats exactly what it means. Does it truly mean that
>   its only available with iOS 6 and up?

Yes, it truly means only available in iOS 6 and later.

Most of the Apple-provided frameworks that you link into your app are dynamic -- they're not built into your app, but linked in when the app launches. They exist on the device as part of the operating system. That means that making retroactive changes such as adding a new method is somewhere between difficult and impossible. Important changes, such as security fixes, are typically made in minor OS updates. Feature changes to the API are usually reserved for more significant upgrades.

Some changes do happen retroactively. For example, object literals work not just in iOS 6 but also in 5 and (I think) even 4. That's because in the case of object literals, the change is in the compiler, not in the operating system or frameworks. As long as you're using a compiler that understands the object literal syntax, the object code that the compiler emits will be compatible with older systems.

Comment: Could you give me an example of an object literal? I could only think of typedefs with respect to literals.

Comment: @RileyE Sure: `@42` gives you a NSNumber with the value 42. See [the docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) for more examples.

Comment: Wow. I knew about the NSString and NSNumber literals (but I didn't even think about them, since they seem so common place), but I didn't have a clue about the other ones! I guess there is still so much I can learn. I am still a newbie with this, though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says.  If it says "2.0 and later" then you can safely use it in any app that target SDK 2.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you can use it starting from this x.x OS version.

Think about this in following way - each feature including API has initial version on which it's born (x.x). It lives for some time (through several versions) and at some point it becomes old (new features can do the same thing, but better) and it's marked as deprecated. It's still could be used, but it's not recommended anymore. And at some moment this feature/API dies (becomes unsupported).

So, if you plan to support iOS 4.3 and up, you will have to choose features which alive in iOS 4.3 to 6.0 (already born, but aren't dead yet).

Comment: So, depreciated doesn't mean "Don't use this". It simply means there is a newer method for later iOS versions, but this can be used for older iOS versions currently. What happens if you release an application that uses a method that "dies" and isn't updated?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Deprecated means "It's going away soon. So, don't use it". If you try to use a method which is dead then your application will fail. However, it's reasonably rare that company kills an API, because all applications which used these API will stop working.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for the help! I really appreciate it. This really cleared up the depreciated method part of my question. I wish I could accept two answers..

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't refer to SDK version - it iOS version. Every version of iOS adds new APIs that it it supports so you can't use an API (like NSTextAlignmentCenter) that don't exist in that version.